# What does “his healthy home already healthy” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Nothing would make a weary traveler’s heart beat a little faster than the luxury of arriving at his healthy home **already healthy**, especially with that built-in juicing station, and a 78-bottle dual-zone wine cooler, on tap for ready rehydration in the germ-free kitchen.

This sentence is from [Health-Centric Homes, for a Price](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/30/realestate/health-centric-homes-for-a-price.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0)

Why use two "healthy" to describe his home? or the latter "healthy" is used to describe something else? I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second "healthy" does not refer to the home, but rather to the weary traveler. It means that he was already healthy before he arrived at his home.

The article that you linked to is talking about an air purification system that the speaker has in his house. This system is what makes his house a "healthy home." He is saying that the system would be a good addition to airports and airplanes because it would allow him to return to his "healthy home" after traveling, and be "already healthy" because he had the air purification system during his travels.

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing would make a weary traveler’s heart beat a little faster than the luxury of arriving at his healthy home **(being) already being healthy**, especially with that built-in juicing station, and a 78-bottle dual-zone wine cooler, on tap for ready rehydration in the germ-free kitchen.
>
> Nothing would make a weary traveler’s heart beat a little faster than the luxury of arriving at his healthy home **while he/she is already healthy**, especially with that built-in juicing station, and a 78-bottle dual-zone wine cooler, on tap for ready rehydration in the germ-free kitchen.

The clause in question appears to be a participle clause and I could convert it to a adverbial one as below.